# How do I refer to a OneToOne model in my views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have no idea how to refer to my OneToOne Field:

```
class Studente(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ore = models.IntegerField()
```

in my views.py file.

```
@login_required(login_url="/home/")
def vistaPrivata(request):
    all_corsi = Corso.objects.all()
    user = request.user
    user_ore = [[ I Dont really know what to write in here  ]]
    template = loader.get_template('corsi/vistaPrivata.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        return redirect('Completa')
    else:
        context = {
            'user_ore' = user_ore,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Can you please help me?
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Read the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField Really, it's all there even with an example.

Comment: `obj=Studente.objects.get(user=request.user)`  will fetch the single Studente object if you do `obj.user` or `obj.ore` you can refer the fields in table.